# How to Use or Install pgAgent on PostgreSQL for Azure

Tags: postgresql, azure

I want to use pgAgent on PostgreSQL. I have PostgreSQL on Azure and I couldn't find any option regarding this on Azure Portal.

**Server Screen**
[image]

Comment: have you tried running `CREATE EXTENSION pgagent`?

Comment: The pgAgent EXTENSION is not available on Azure.

Comment: that explains a lot :-D